# Migrating Windows DNS from server to server both 2012

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

From my understanding if both servers have AD as a DC with DNS, the DNS is migrated automatically. The main server(old one) is a DC but the new one is just a DNS server. So in this case is there a way to export then import DNS records? Or can I treat Windows DNS servers like BIND and setup a secondary zone and then have replication and forwarding them that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the zones as secondary zones on the standalone DNS server and add that server to the name servers tab of the AD DNS server and configure the Zone Transfer settings on the AD DNS server to allow zone transfers to the new server.